# What exactly do we know about Heaven?

Tags: heaven, biblical-basis

Most of us probably have a lot of vague ideas about Heaven, the place where the faithful are said to spend their afterlife. But when I really start to think about it, I can't back most of my ideas with the Bible.

What do we actually know about Heaven?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment as it's not suitable as an answer, but Randy Alcorn's "Heaven" answers this question in great detail.

Comment: To clarify, are you specifically referring to the "place" where Believers are said to spend eternity after death?  Or do you want answers that address all the possible uses of the word "heaven" in scripture?

Comment: @Flimzy I was asking about the place. That requires biblical knowledge as not all passages that talk about Heaven have the word.

Comment: This question is an [inverted tag](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heaven).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's the dwelling place of God the Father**

[Matthew 6:9 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206:9&version=NIV)

> “This, then, is how you should pray:
>
> “‘Our Father in heaven, 
>   hallowed be your name

**It's a place of treasures that thieves can't steal.**

[Matthew 6:20 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%206:20&version=NIV)

> But store up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where moths and vermin do not destroy, and where thieves do not break in and steal.

**It has many rooms**

[John 14:2 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:2&version=NIV)

> **2** My Father’s house has many rooms; if that were not so, would I have told you that I am going there to prepare a place for you?

**It's an actual place**

[John 14:2-4 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:2-4&version=NIV)

> **2** My Father’s house has many rooms; if that were not so, would I have told you that I am going there to prepare a place for you? **3** And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come back and take you to be with me that you also may be where I am. **4** You know the way to the place where I am going.

**It's being prepared for us**

Compare this to the idea that it's just a "state of being".  It's not.  It's a place that is being prepared.

[John 14:2 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:2&version=NIV) supports this.  Also:

Jesus said in [Matthew 25:34 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025:34&version=NIV)

> "Then the King will say to those on his right, ‘Come, you who are blessed by my Father; take your inheritance, the kingdom prepared for you since the creation of the world."

**It's a place of reward**

This is in the middle of a parable that Jesus was telling regarding what heaven would be like.

[Matthew 25:23 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025:23&version=NIV)

> His master replied, ‘Well done, good and faithful servant! You have been faithful with a few things; I will put you in charge of many things. Come and share your master’s happiness!’

**There won't be a need for marriage in heaven**

[Luke 20:34-36 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2020:34-36&version=NIV)

> **34** Jesus replied, “The people of this age marry and are given in marriage. **35** But those who are considered worthy of taking part in the age to come and in the resurrection from the dead will neither marry nor be given in marriage, **36** and they can no longer die; for they are like the angels. They are God’s children, since they are children of the resurrection.

**It is everlasting/eternal**

[John 3:16 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:16&version=NIV)

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

Comment: +1 and good answer, but [didn't you miss one](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-exactly-do-we-know-about-heaven/1987#1987)?

Comment: That's true.  I mentioned God, but didn't include Jesus in that.  (Granted, an argument could be made about the trinity etc., but really I did miss that one.) ;)  Honestly, I probably missed more than one.  Those were just the easy ones.

Answer (score 4):

Richard made an excellent [list of various details that we know about heaven](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-exactly-do-we-know-about-heaven/1036#1036), however I feel he made one oversight -- perhaps like missing the forest through the trees.

I would just like to zoom in on one detail: the centerpiece -- or zoom way out if you will for this detail is the *magnum opus of heaven*.

**Heaven is where Christ is. Seated in victory at the right hand of God.**

If there was one single thing that we should be expecting to find when we get to heaven, it is Jesus. Over and over in the NT when heaven is mentioned, it is frequently paired with the detail that Jesus will be there.

If you are hoping for anything else, your hopes are mis-directed. If you are longing for his presence more than anything you will not be disappointed!

> **[Colossians 3:1](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+3/)** (ESV)
> If then you have been raised with Christ, seek the things that are above, *where Christ is, seated at the right hand of God*.
>
> **[Hebrews 12:2](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Hebrews%2012:2)** (ESV)
> looking to *Jesus*, the founder and perfecter of our faith, who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross, despising the shame, and *is seated at the right hand of the throne of God*.
>
> **[Luke 22:69](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Luke%2022:69)** (ESV)
> But from now on the *Son of Man shall be seated at the right hand of the power of God*.”
>
> **[Mark 14:62](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Mark%2014:62)** (ESV)
> And Jesus said, “I am, and you will see the *Son of Man seated at the right hand of Power*, and coming with the clouds of heaven.”

For further reading on how the heavenly hosts focus Christ's presence, read [Revelations 5](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Revelation%205:1/).

Comment: You're very much right. I feel a little inclined to change this to the accepted answer, but I'd rather see the two answers combined.